# Can't get any response back while calling service through frisbyJS

Tags: angularjs, frisby.js

The code I am using is:

```
var frisby = require('frisby');
frisby.create('Get paf data')
.get('https://services.....')
.expectStatus(200)
.expectHeaderContains('content-type', 'application/json')
.toss();
```

The error I get while running it from CLI using

```
jasmine-node EndpointTest_spec.js
```

The error I get is:

Error: Expected 500 to equal 200

Error: Header 'content-type' not present in HTTP response

So do I need to first load my website and call services through my application and then run frisby ?

But then it defeats the purpose of just making a quick check for all the endpoints used in application without running it.

Comment: Probably you are behind a proxy. Is that the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling request with **https://** which may be secure server  so use

> { strictSSL: false} in your get method **.get('https://services.....',{ strictSSL: false})**. It will solve your problem.

```
var frisby = require('frisby');
frisby.create('Get paf data')
  .get('https://services.....',{ strictSSL: false})
  .expectStatus(200)
  .expectHeaderContains('content-type', 'application/json')
.toss();
```